# Как при нажатии на одну и ту же ссылку, добавлять при каждом клике новый блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например первый раз кликнул, добавился блок красного цвета, второй раз кликнул на эту же ссылку, добавился блок синего цвета и так далее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery:

```js
var color = [
  "red",
  "green",
  "blue"
];

$(function() {
  var add_block = $("#add_block");

  add_block.click(function() {
    $("#blocks").append("<div style=\"background: " + color[$("#blocks div").length] + " \">test</div>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_block">Добавить блок</button>

<div id="blocks"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var colors = [
  "red",
  "green",
  "blue"
];

window.onload = function() {
  var add_block = document.getElementById("add_block");
  var blocks = document.getElementById("blocks");

  add_block.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.background = colors[blocks.getElementsByTagName("div").length];
    div.innerHTML = "test"; 

    blocks.appendChild(div);
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<button id="add_block">Добавить блок</button>

<div id="blocks"></div>
```

P.S. Мы создаём массив с цветами и при клике на кнопку `Добавить блок`, добавляем div-элемент в `<div id="blocks"></div>`. Цвет определяется так:

У нас есть массив color:

```
// colors[0] => red  
// colors[1] => green
```

Вместо нуля или единицы, как показано выше (да и в прочем цифра будет любая) мы подставляем количество уже созданных блоков. То есть, если создан 1 элемент, то по условию нашего кода следующий цвет для `div-блока` будет `green`, затем `blue` и так далее.